# Call a method on Popbackstack()

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I replace Fragment-A with Fragment-B, and on calling popbackstack() in Fragment-B i will redirect back to Fragment-A. So I wanted to call a method that will update the list.

Answer (score 1):

One more importance difference between add and replace is: replace removes the existing fragment and adds a new fragment. This means when you press back button the fragment that got replaced will be created with its onCreateView being invoked. Whereas add retains the existing fragments and adds a new fragment that means existing fragment will be active and they wont be in 'paused' state hence when a back button is pressed onCreateView is not called for the existing fragment(the fragment which was there before new fragment was added). In terms of fragment's life cycle events onPause, onResume, onCreateView and other life cycle events will be invoked in case of replace but they wont be invoked in case of add.

In Short for your use case, you need to use add and if you don't want the fragment views to overlap then you might replace the Fragment B view background color with a solid color instead of transparent.

When you add your fragment, you also have to add it to your fragment's backstack.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                  ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment, backStateName);
                  ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
                  ft.commit();
```

(here R.id.content is your fragment container in your activity)

Then you have to override onBackPressed method in your activity that contains your fragments.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                 getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  }
}
```

if you want to customize your onBackPressed then you can check for your currently visible fragment in your activity and create a callback for performing action for that particular fragment. example -

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
              Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);
              if (fragment instanceof FragmentB) {
                            ((FragmentB) fragment).onBackPressed();
//                     getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
      }
    }
```

now you can add getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); in your Fragment's onBackPressed() method.